# React CSS order of application

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

**In a React app created with Create React App, what do I need to do to have my SCSS styles applied in the correct order?**

For example, in `<div className="page page-form page-login">`, I would expect React to apply my styles in the order:

1. `.page`
2. `.page-form`
3. `.page-login`

Meaning, the styles defined in `.page-login` are suppossed to override any styles defined in `.page-form` or `.page`.

However, in practice I find that the styles defined in `.page` override the other styles. I find that the only way to override the styles defined in `.page` is to add `!important` in `.page-login`.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Change the order of rules in your stylesheet

Comment: use scss and use like .page { ... &-form { ... } &-login{ ... }  }

Comment: `.page` and `.page-form` are defined in `App.scss` (in this order) and `.page-login` is defined in a different scss file that is included in the corresponding component.

Comment: Re-order lines which do the `import` ?

Comment: @ThanhTrung Where and how?

Comment: Right, I think I got it worked out. In App.js, I import all my React components (which themselves import their own scss files) and then I import App.scss below those component imports. When I move the import of App.scss above the imports of my other components, it appears to work!